# How to find multiple tags at once along with attributes using BeautifulSoup in python3?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to find different tags at once using `find_all()` method of BeautifulSoup. I found a way to include all tags in the list to get the respective tags. But I am trying to get tags along with their attributes. I am not sure how to get it.

This is the reference HTML structure.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h4>Registered Customer Details</h4>
            <div>
                <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-3'>Name :</div>
                <div class='col-6'>ABC</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-3'>Address :</div>
                <div class='col-6'>India</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-6 col-12 lo">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img alt="image" class="img-responsive" src="/uploads/NEWLOGO.png"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <h4>Partner Details</h4>
            <div>
                <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-4'>Partners :</div>
                <div class='col-8'><table></table></div>
            </div>
            <div class="span3"></div>
            <div class="span9"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to find tags at once.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('test.html','r').read(),'lxml')
soup.find_all(['h4','div'])
```

The above script will return all h4 tags and all div tags, but I'm looking for all h4 tags and all div tags having class value as col-3, col-6, col-4 & col-8.

Which might look something like this,

```
# for single value
soup.find_all(['h4', ['div',{'class':'col-3'}] ])

# for multiple value
soup.find_all(['h4', ['div',{'class':['col-3','col-6','col-4','col-8']}] ])
```

> Output:

```
[<h4>Registered Customer Details</h4>, <h4>Partner Details</h4>]
```

> Expected output:

```
[<h4>Registered Customer Details</h4>,
 <div class='col-3'>Name :</div>,
 <div class='col-6'>ABC</div>,
 <div class='col-3'>Address :</div>,
 <div class='col-6'>India</div>,
 <h4>Partner Details</h4>,
 <div class='col-4'>Partners :</div>,
 <div class='col-8'><table></table>]
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the expected output?

Comment: So, for example, `<div class='col-3'>'Key1'</div>` should **not** be in the output?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand: you're interested **only** in the `<h4>` tags? You don't care about any of the `<div>`s?

Comment: @JackFleeting As mentioned, I'm looking for both i.e all h4 tags and all div tags with class as col-3, col-6,....

Comment: @David So could you update your output to exactly what you expect to get, to clarify. It's a bit confused at the moment. Would be great - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try writing this-

```
# for single value
soup.find_all(['h4','div'], class_='col-3')

# for multiple value
soup.find_all(['h4','div'], class_=['col-3','col-4'])
```

Comment: I tried but it missing the h4 tag in output as h4 tag doesn't have any class with matching value.

Output:

<div class="col-3">'Key1'</div>
<div class="col-3">'Key1'</div>
<div class="col-4">'Key4'</div>

Comment: Okay. My answer was written before you edited the question and added the expected output. In that case, @HedgeHog's answer is best tuned to your specific use case

Answer (score 0):

*First of all HTML should be valid to be sure parser is working as expected. There are closing tags missing.*

One option that would work for your example is the following [`css selector`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select('h4,div[class^="col-"]')
```

You could adapt it and make it more specific if needed:

```
soup.select('h4, div.row  div[class^="col-"]')
...
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h4>Registered Customer Details</h4>
            <div>
                <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-3'>Name :</div>
                <div class='col-6'>ABC</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-3'>Address :</div>
                <div class='col-6'>India</div>
            </div>
            <h4>Partner Details</h4>
            <div>
                <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-4'>Partners :</div>
                <div class='col-8'><table></table></div>
            </div>
            <div class="span3"></div>
            <div class="span9"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,)

soup.select('h4,div[class^="col-"]')
```

###### Output

```
[<h4>Registered Customer Details</h4>,
 <div class="col-3">Name :</div>,
 <div class="col-6">ABC</div>,
 <div class="col-3">Address :</div>,
 <div class="col-6">India</div>,
 <h4>Partner Details</h4>,
 <div class="col-4">Partners :</div>,
 <div class="col-8"><table></table></div>]
```

Comment: Thanks that almost getting the required output. I ran the script in original site html, but there are similar unwanted 'div' tags having multiple class within same div as 'col-3 col-4' which is also coming. Is there a way to avoid that as well. I've updated the html structure for reference.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it has already helped you once. As noted, you can adapt the approach and adjust it to your specific requirements; from my point of view, the selection listed there as an example fulfils exactly this requirement. Have you tried it out?

Comment: Yes I tried, it works to some extent like passing `div[class^="col-"]` will give div with class as <div class="col-3">,<div class="col-6"> as well as <div class="col-3 col-6">. But I am focusing on div having class as single col `<div class="col-">`. So if we try with space `div[class^="col- "]`,(with *)`div[class^="col-*"]`or(both) as `div[class^="col-* "]`,it gives nothing not even a single div. And if we think of hard-coding specific col in class as `div[class^="col-3"]`,`div[class^="col-4"]`,or by combining as `soup.select('h4, div[class^="col-4"],div[class^="col-8"]')` we are getting it.

Comment: Not sure if we talk about the same - Mentioned line `soup.select('h4, div.row  div[class^="col-"]')` is doing what you need for your edited example.